# Can I add another clownfish?

Tags: clownfish

I have a 15 gallon column tank. It has live rock and a pair of ocellaris clownfish. I was wondering if I could add one black ocellaris clown. My pair likes hiding in a patch of plant and I really would like to add another fish. [image] I want the fish to thrive and I don't want to accidentally kill a fish just because I think a black one would look nice in the tank. The two I have no aren't aggressive, besides when I feed them. The female will chase the male but not too aggressively, like she doesn't hurt him. Can somebody please let me know? Thank you